# How can I change the size of icons in the Tree control in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, tree, icons

I embed SVG graphics in my Flex application using

```
package MyUI
{
    public class Assets
    {
        [Embed(source="/assets/pic.svg"]
        [Bindable]
        public static var svgPic:Class;
    }
}
```

and then extending the Tree class with some of my own code, setting the icon upon adding a node to the data provider:

```
public class MyTree extends Tree
{
    public function MyTree()
    {
        // ...
        this.iconField = "svgIcon";
        // ...
        this.dataProvider = new ArrayCollection;
        this.dataProvider.addItem({ /* ... */ svgIcon: MyUI.Assets.svgPic /* ... */ });
        // ...
    }
}
```

Now I have two things I want to do:

- use the SVG graphics in multiple places in the app, scaling them to the appropriate size for each appearance, i. e. scale them to a proper icon size when using them in the tree
- change the size of the icon at runtime, e. g. display a slightly larger icon for selected items or let an icon "pulse" as a response to some event

I read the Flex documentation on the 9-slice scaling properties in the Embed tag, but I think that's not what I want.

---

Edit:

I unsuccessfully checked the "similar questions" suggested by SO, among others this one:

[Flex: Modify an embedded icon and use it in a button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160250/flex-modify-an-embedded-icon-and-use-it-in-a-button)

Answer (score 1):

Subclass [mx.controls.treeClasses.TreeItemRenderer](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/treeClasses/TreeItemRenderer.html) and make it resize the icon to your desired dimensions, or create your own item renderer implementation by using the same interfaces as TreeItemRenderer. Set a custom item renderer with the `itemRenderer` property:

```
exampleTree.itemRenderer = new ClassFactory( ExampleCustomItemRendererClass );
```

Comment: OK, that solves my initial sizing, but can I resize the icons at runtime, too?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Do you want the icons to resize at runtime in the Tree based on some event or another input?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question might point you in the right direction, without knowing more about the trouble you're having:

[Flex: Modify an embedded icon and use it in a button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160250/flex-modify-an-embedded-icon-and-use-it-in-a-button)

Hope it helps!